# Что такое expression statement? Что такое литералы? Являются 1, 2, 3 или 'a' экземплярами или объектами класса? И чем отличается объект от экземпляра?

Tags: c++

Что такое `expression statement`? Что такое литерал? И является ли `'a'` экземпляром типа char, а `1` экземпляром типа int. И чем отличается объект класса от экземпляра класса?

Comment: *`"И чем отличается объект класса от экземпляра класса?"`* -- ничем, экземпляр и объект это синонимы

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. `expression statements` - это присваивание или вызовы функций/методов, вообщем большая часть кода на c++ - это именно `expression statements`
2. литерал - это константы, которые вставляются непосредственно в код (магические числа, дэфайны и прочее)
3. является ли `'a'` экземпляром `char` - `'a'` в коде это литерал, не `char`
4. цифра `1` в коде тоже литерал
5. зависит от того, что подразумевается под "экземпляром" - я могу ошибаться, но мне кажется, что это не является общеупотребительным определением (если я правильно использовал 2 последних слова)